# Group Related Records in a Query

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to group related records.  The table I am working with contains identity pairs that are unique.  Related records are records where one of the identities is equal to the same identity in another record.

For example if a record has 384 and 768 for ID1 and ID2, then another record with 384 and 512 for ID1 and ID2, it would be related.  Also, another record with 256 and 768 would also be related.  However, a record with 1024 and 1536 would not be related.

The sample table and data are below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Identities](
    [AN] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ID1] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ID2] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Identities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [AN] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [AK_ID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID1] ASC,
        [ID2] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Identities] ([AN], [ID1], [ID2], [LastUpdateDate])
VALUES
    ('00243', '6000086', '2200720', '2016-05-26 17:16:07.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00267', '6000752', '5700243', '2017-06-21 12:24:55.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00284', '6000086', '5000385', '2020-02-11 11:56:01.0000000 -05:00')
,   ('00352', '6000752', '2200720', '2016-05-31 20:08:47.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00360', '6000752', '6000779', '2019-04-17 20:46:15.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00475', '6200598', '5000385', '2017-06-21 18:29:49.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00507', '6200599', '5000385', '2017-06-21 18:37:21.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00558', '6200606', '5000385', '2017-06-21 18:14:51.0000000 -04:00')
,   ('00735', '5500045', '2200721', '2018-10-11 15:30:50.0000000 -04:00')
GO
```

From this sample data, the desired output is below.

```
AN      ID1     ID2     LastUpdateDate                      Group
00243   6000086 2200720 2016-05-26 17:16:07.0000000 -04:00  1
00267   6000752 5700243 2017-06-21 12:24:55.0000000 -04:00  1
00284   6000086 5000385 2020-02-11 11:56:01.0000000 -05:00  1
00352   6000752 2200720 2016-05-31 20:08:47.0000000 -04:00  1
00360   6000752 6000779 2019-04-17 20:46:15.0000000 -04:00  1
00475   6200598 5000385 2017-06-21 18:29:49.0000000 -04:00  1
00507   6200599 5000385 2017-06-21 18:37:21.0000000 -04:00  1
00558   6200606 5000385 2017-06-21 18:14:51.0000000 -04:00  1
00735   5500045 2200721 2018-10-11 15:30:50.0000000 -04:00  2
```

I believe this can be achieved with a recursive query.  Possibly something similar to the solution here:[Recursively Querying Row Groups](https://bertwagner.com/2020/08/25/recursively-querying-row-groups/), but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need 2 recursive cte's because the links have to go in 2 directions.
Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS--recursive cte id2
  (SELECT i1.ID1, i1.ID2
   FROM [dbo].[Identities] i1

   UNION ALL 
   
   SELECT c.ID1,i2.ID1
   FROM [dbo].[Identities] i2
   JOIN cte c ON c.ID2 = i2.ID2
   )   ,

cte2 AS--recursive cte id1
  (SELECT i1.ID1, i1.ID2
   FROM [dbo].[Identities] i1

   UNION ALL 
   
   SELECT c.ID2, i2.ID2
   FROM [dbo].[Identities] i2
   JOIN cte c ON c.ID1 = i2.ID1
   )   ,

cte3 AS--union both recursive cte's
  (SELECT *
   FROM cte
   UNION 
   SELECT *
   FROM cte2
   ),
     
cte4 AS--group
  (SELECT id1, min(id2) AS id2, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY min(id2)) AS grp
   FROM cte3
   GROUP BY id1)

SELECT i.AN,i.ID1,i.ID2,i.LastUpdateDate,c.grp
FROM cte4 c
JOIN [dbo].[Identities] i ON i.id1 = c.id1
```